# Apache2 only shows index, but know other sides

Tags: configuration, apache2, debian

i need help at my Apache2 Configuration, other Threads didnt work for me :(
Ive got the wheezy on my Raspberry Pi, which are Debian.
Ive installed Apache2 PHP and MySQL like showen in a How-To.
It worked fine, index.php would work on my server, with php-code all fine.
But if i add a secound site or add an css\file.css i would get following message in the error.log:

```
[Thu Mar 14 14:15:55 2013] [error] [client 212.184.119.18] (13)Permission denied                         : file permissions deny server access: /var/www/style.html
[Thu Mar 14 14:15:57 2013] [error] [client 212.184.119.18] (13)Permission denied                         : access to /css/coolblue.css denied, referer: http://myNAME.dyndns-at-home.com/
```

i didnt know how to fix this Permission, please give me a hint.

if you need more informations please tell me i would give it to you ;-)
Sorry for my bad english.
Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You should check the permissions of the directory where the new site has been placed or the permissions of the files that you have created.
This files and directories must be readable by the user or the group of the Apache server.

For example:
List the files or the directories:

```
ls -la
```

Set the required directory permission with

```
chmod 750 site_directory
chown webeditoruser:apachegroup site_directory
```

Set the required permissions for the files with

```
chmod 640 your_file.ext
chown webeditoruser:apachegroup your_file.ext
```

Comment: yea thank you now it work I didnt know that it was so easy thank you ;-)